# Passing data from HTML to JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of data points that I query for status and voltage, and **want to use a function to display as readable data in a table**.

I can't seem to get how to **pass the register data to the fnction**, and then **return the processed data to the table**.

*Here's the test code,*

```
<input type="hidden" id="reg120" name="reg120" readonly value="%d">
<input type="hidden" id="reg121" name="reg121" readonly value="%d">

<script language="javascript">

function dsestate(regn) {

    var state = ["STOP MODE","AUTO MODE","MANUAL MODE","TEST ON LOAD","AUTO MAN","USER CONF","TEST OFF LOAD","OFF"];
    return state[regn];
    }

</script>

<script language="javascript">

function divby10(regn1) {
    return regn1/10;
    }   

</script>

<table id="maintable" style="width:75%">

  <tr>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th style="width:180px">Status</th> 
    <th style="width:180px">Voltage</th>

   </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td><input type="text" id="dsestate(reg120)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="divby10(reg121)"></td>
   </tr>




</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: WHat are you trying to acheive ?

Comment: Few Clarifications, why do you have a hidden input on top it seems like you don't use it for any data entry? By id ="dsestate(reg120)" do you mean set the value of that input element to the value returned by dsestate(reg120), where reg120 is the value obtained from the hidden input text?

Comment: your input `<input type="text" id="dsestate(reg120)">` should be a dropdown instead I think

Comment: First thank you all for helping!  What I am trying to do is to pull state data from a network monitoring device that queries a number of generators (via modbus) and stores the state data in registers.  The test code here is attempting to pull the generator status register and the voltage register.  Then, I want to display the text lookup for the status and the voltage in a table that will eventually have multiple rows.

Comment: The hidden input is the register data.  My attempt at calling a function was to pass the register value to the function, and return the processed value.  So for example to first read reg120, then pass it to function dsestate and return text "AUTO MODE"

Answer (score 0):

divBy10's argument should be a number (so it could be divided by 10).
dsestate's argument should also be a number so you can get the object by the index of the state Array (i.e. state[1]).

And since you're calling a javascript function, it should also use onload=, rather than id=.

I hope that gives you a starting point, good luck!